# How do I apply a function to a dataframe and then to a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, tibble

I need to calculate the rolling three-month return for multiple investment portfolios. I would like to apply a function to achieve this because I have several portfolios and benchmarks to calculate this for.

For the sake of my understanding

- I first want to know how to calculate it on one dataframe using an
  apply method.
- Then, I would like to know how to apply a similar function to a list of dataframes.

**The dataframe**

```
    stefi <- tibble::tribble(    ~date ,  ~return,
                           1996-04-30,   0.0126,
                           1996-05-31,   0.0126,
                           1996-06-30,   0.0119,
                           1996-07-31,   0.0144,
                           1996-08-31,   0.0132,
                           1996-09-30,   0.0136,
                           1996-10-31,   0.0135,
                           1996-11-30,   0.0127,
                           1996-12-31,   0.0143,
                           1997-01-31,   0.0144)
```

**My attempt at a function**

Here is my function to calculate the three-month return. The math is fine, but I'm not sure whether it's supposed to return a vector, variable, or something else for the purpose of the `apply` method I need to use.

```
    calc_3m_return <- function(x){
      
      y <- (x + 1) *
        ((lag(X, 1)) + 1) *
        ((lag(X, 2)) + 1) - 1
      
      return(y)
      
    }
```

I'm not having luck with `apply` or `lapply`.

```
lapply(stefi$return, calc_3m_return, return)
```

**R's output**

```
> lapply(stefi$return, calc_3m_return, return)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (return)
```

**What I can get working**

I manage to get the desired result with the following steps:

```
#Calculate return function
calc_3m_return <- function(return){
  
  y <- (return + 1) *
    ((lag(return, 1)) + 1) *
    ((lag(return, 2)) + 1) - 1
  
  return(y)
  
}

#Calculate 3-month return and append it to the dataframe
stefi <- stefi %>%
  mutate(return_3m = calc_3m_return(return))
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  date       return return_3m
  <date>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1996-04-30 0.0126   NA     
2 1996-05-31 0.0126   NA     
3 1996-06-30 0.0119    0.0376
4 1996-07-31 0.0144    0.0395
5 1996-08-31 0.0132    0.0401
6 1996-09-30 0.0136    0.0418
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (`ldf` contains a list of dataframes, as wanted):

```
library(tidyverse)

stefi <- tibble::tribble(    ~date ,  ~return,
                             1996-04-30,   0.0126,
                             1996-05-31,   0.0126,
                             1996-06-30,   0.0119,
                             1996-07-31,   0.0144,
                             1996-08-31,   0.0132,
                             1996-09-30,   0.0136,
                             1996-10-31,   0.0135,
                             1996-11-30,   0.0127,
                             1996-12-31,   0.0143,
                             1997-01-31,   0.0144)
ldf <- list(stefi,stefi)

calc_3m_return <- function(x){
  
  y <- (x + 1) *
    ((lag(x, 1)) + 1) *
    ((lag(x, 2)) + 1) - 1
  
  return(y)
}

map(ldf, ~ {.x$return_3m <- calc_3m_return(.x$return); .x})

# Or alternatively
# map(ldf, ~ tibble(.x, return_3m = calc_3m_return(.x$return)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I don't understand the "map" function, so I'll need to study that to understand how this solution works.

Comment: You are welcome! The function `map` belongs to `purrr` package: [Apply a function to each element of a list or atomic vector](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

Comment: I see in the documentation that this is the "formula" application of the `map` function, which I assume is because it's denoted with `~`. What does `; .x` do at the end of that line? I don't see a similar syntax in the documentation.

Comment: The function here has two lines of code. Therefore, it is necessary to separate them by `;`, since the two lines of code are condensed in a single line of code. The `{}` are also necessary because there is the above-mentioned separator `;`.

Comment: But, @BanditKing, you may want to use a simpler approach by replacing the last line of my code by the following one: `map(ldf, ~ tibble(.x, return_3m = calc_3m_return(.x$return)))`

Comment: Thank you Paul - I will try that too. I'm probably pushing my luck here trying to sponge more advice, but do you know how I can make that function calculate the return since inception? In Excel, the formula would be `=PRODUCT($B$2:$B307+1)^(12/COUNT($B$2:$B307))-1`, where the cell references would be to the time series of monthly returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238405/discussion-between-bandit-king-and-paul-smith).